# Getting issue under SQL View error (The MAX function requires 1 argument(s).)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting error "The MAX function requires 1 argument(s)" while running below view. Please anybody help me on it.

```
CREATE VIEW SQL_RP("ID_NUMERIC", "SAMPLING_POINT", "SAMPLED_DATE", "COMPOSITE_INTERVAL", "TEST_NUMBER", "ANALYSIS", "TEST_COUNT", "COMPONENT_NAME", "RESULT_VALUE", "RESULT_TEXT", "UNITS", "RESULT_TYPE", "RESULT_STATUS", "ENTERED_BY", "UPDATED_DATE")

AS

  SELECT sample.id_numeric,

    sample.sampling_point,
    sample.sampled_date,
    sample.composite_interval,
    test.test_number,
    test.analysis,
    test.test_count,
    result.name  AS component_name,
    result.Value AS result_value,
    result.text  AS result_text,
    result.units,
    result.result_type,
    result.status AS result_status,
    result.entered_by,
    MAX (ISNULL(test.date_authorised, (GETDATE - 365*100)), ISNULL(result.entered_on, (GETDATE - 365*100)), ISNULL(result.date_authorised, (GETDATE - 365*100)), ISNULL(esav.audit_date, (GETDATE - 365*100)) ) AS updated_date
  FROM sample
  INNER JOIN test
  ON sample.id_numeric = test.sample
  INNER JOIN result
  ON test.test_number = result.test_number
  LEFT OUTER JOIN eims_sample_audit_view esav 
  ON esav.id_numeric   = sample.id_numeric
  WHERE result.status <> 'U';
```

Answer (score 1):

`MAX()` is an aggregation function, not a scalar function.  What you really want is `GREATEST()`, but SQL Server does not have such a function (although most databases do).

This can be a pain using `CASE` because of nulls, so the simplest way is probably `OUTER APPLY` in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT . . .,
       v.updated_date
FROM sample JOIN
     test
     ON sample.id_numeric = test.sample
     result JOIN
     ON test.test_number = result.test_number LEFT JOIN
     eims_sample_audit_view esav (alias)  -- huh?
     ON esav.id_numeric = sample.id_numeric OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(dte) as updated_date
      FROM (VALUES (test.date_authorised),
                   (result.entered_on),
                   (result.date_authorised),
                   (esav.audit_date),
                   (GETDATE() - 365*100)
           ) v(dte)
     ) v;
```

Comment: Getting below error ("Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' and
Incorrect syntax near 'v'")

Comment: @user3258671 . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle.  Nothing is obviously wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is v.updated_date? Actually am getting error "Incorrect syntax near 'v'."

Comment: Can you please help me on which purposes you have used v.updated_date as am getting syntax error 'V'